# Get user comment in post using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I read almost topic related about value is null in restfb and almost is miss Parameter() method or something else. But my problem isn't those reason.
I don't know why I can't get user comment in post and result is null although in Graph API Explorer, I can get it. I using Graph API v2.10 because v2.11 can't get user comment .

```
static AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_10).obtainAppAccessToken(Constants.MY_APP_ID,Constants.MY_APP_SECRET);
```

Here is my code:

```
Connection<Comment> commentDetails = facebookClient.fetchConnection(aPost.getId()+ "/comments", Comment.class, 
                        Parameter.with("fields", "message,from{id,name}"));
                if(comments !=null){
                        List<Comment> commentList = commentDetails.getData();
                        System.out.println("---------Comments----------");
                        for(Comment comment : commentList){
                            System.out.println(comment.getMessage() + " - " + comment.getId());
                            System.out.println(" - " + comment.getFrom().getName()); //line 101

                    }

                }
```

In console, I see I can get `commentId` and `commentMessage` but `getFrom()` is null.

Below is my output:

`Dear Bill...God blessed you & your family..you are smart & having a lot of money but most importantly you & Melinda has big golden hearts...way to go for helping humans special who they need more..love u & ur family & praying for u all - 10155024059741961_10155024134711961
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SimpleMeExample.main(SimpleMeExample.java:101)`

Comment: Can you please update your post to include the output from running the program and the stack trace if you got a null pointer exception?

Comment: @Loren I updated my question. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: I solved my promblem. Because my access token not enough permission. Thank for your support